# TeamCity Allowing Successful Builds in Spite of Failed Tests

Tags: maven, junit, teamcity

I am using TeamCity and JUnit to build and test some software I am writing. Because I am using a test-driven development pattern, I build Unit tests that will test how a feature should work (initially it always fails because the feature hasn't been implemented yet), and then I develop the feature until it passes all of the tests that it should.

In TeamCity I have two build steps: The first is a Maven build step which compiles my project, the second is another Maven build step which only runs the unit tests. What I would like to do is find a way for the "Build Success" to be determined by the success or failure of the first step, and then get a listing of all of the tests that pass or fail as a separate portion of the build log. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it turns out that what I want to do needs to be configured in the maven pom like so:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This allows the build to complete if some tests fail like this:
[image: Successful Build with Failed Tests]

Answer (score 3):

You can change the failure scenarios of a build within TeamCity by going into the Settings tab of the build and modifying the "Build Failure Conditions" options.

[image]

You can turn off "at least one test failed" as a failure condition.  This will allow the build to succeed as long as everything compiled.

Comment: It is a combination of this answer and either Brendon or V0rin's answer to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

For TeamCity adding this line `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true` to "Additional Maven command line parameters:" in Build Step works

Answer (score -2):

> Because I am using a test-driven development pattern, I build Unit
>   tests that will test how a feature should work and then I develop the
>   feature until it passes all of the tests that it should.

Sorry mate, this is not test driven development at all. In TDD you always write just **one failing test**, then you implement just enough code to satisfy the test expectations and then you refactor. When all tests (the new one and older as well) passes you can integrate your changes with others.

It is possible to set-up TeamCity in the way you want, but it does not make any sense.

Comment: Sorry mate but that is incorrect. TDD practiced Outside-In style will include a failing "Acceptance" test until it passes at which point it will become a "Regression" test. An in-dev Acceptance test can (and should) fail. A Regression test should not fail. Not everyone practices TDD in the same way as you.

Comment: I follow TDD as Kent Beck explained it. Otherwise it is not TDD but test first.